# Putting splitted strings into each row

Tags: sql, split

my problem is this:

Imagine having a table (People), and we have a column called name with 5 rows,  so in our case:

```
Name:
Enrique West
Damien Braun
Ellie Osborne
Cierra Vega
Alden Cantrell
```

And then we have another column, which is called surname. This column is empty.
Now I need the sql code to put the surname for all of those people in the surname column. 
So then we should have:

```
Surname:
West
Braun
Osborne
Vega
Cantrell
```

I tried this:

```
Update People
set Surname =
(SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 23, 20)
from People)
where condition
```

I currently get this error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the 
subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an 
expression.
```

Important is that each row, for example the row with Enrique West, only includes his surname.

What should I add or change to the code?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Add Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Carl van der Walt and Jonathan Rhys-Davies  to the sample data too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a subquery!  Just:

```
Update People
    set Surname = SUBSTRING(name, 23, 20)
    where condition;
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution!